# Replace word with another word in long string in nested array

Tags: javascript

My path are like below in my tree structure :

```
Node                : /myPath/Node 
     Node-1         : /myPath/Node/Node-1
       Node-1-1     : /myPath/Node/Node-1-1
```

Now if my current object record from Node then from that node I would like to travel every child nodes of it and replace **Node with First.**

Expected output will be :

```
Node                : /myPath/First
     Node-1         : /myPath/First/Node-1
       Node-1-1     : /myPath/First/Node-1-1
```

With my current code problem is it is only replacing **search term(First)** at first node but not for each of the child node.

```js
var currentObj = 
  {
    "name": "Node",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "Node-1",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "Node-1-1",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "name": "Node-1-1-1",
                "nodes": [
                  
                ],
                "path": "/myPath/Node/Node-1/Node-1-1/Node-1-1-1"
              }
            ],
            "path": "/myPath/Node/Node-1/Node-1-1"
          }
        ],
        "path": "/myPath/Node/Node-1"
      }
    ],
    "path": "/myPath/Node"
  };

recursive(currentObj,"First");
console.log(currentObj);

 function recursive(node,replace)
    {
          console.log(node.path);
           node.path = replaceAll(node.path,'Node',replace);
    } 
      
        function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
        return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
    }
    
    function escapeRegExp(str) {
        return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively calling `recursive` for each node in `nodes` seems to work:

```
function recursive(node)
{
    node.path = replaceAll(node.path,'Node','First');
    node.nodes.forEach(recursive);
}
```

With extra arguments:

```
node.nodes.forEach(function(child_node) {
    recursive(child_node, arg1, arg2);
});
```

Comment: Ok upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but if suppose i have 2 parameters in recursive method then how to call recursive methodl with loop?

Comment: I have taken a variable called as searchTerm and i have assign that variable this value and so i will pass searchTerm as a parameter to recursive function instead of hardcoding it in replaceAll function but problem is it gets lost when recursive is call for the second time

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can add extra arguments.